# Count non blank cells in row x

Tags: excel, vba

What Im trying to achieve is to count non blank cells in row `lRow`. I got error on third line of the macro. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
Sub CountNonEmptyCells()

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Rows(lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Count
    MsgBox lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(lRow))` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, I fixed it myself:

```
Sub CountNonEmptyCells()

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    x = Rows(lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Cells.Count
    MsgBox x

End Sub
```